# How is startup_32 at address 0x100000?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

I was reading about how the Linux Kernel prepares to enter protected mode. Everything is understandable until, in boot/pmjump.S:74, we are jumping to 0x100000, which is in EAX.

[image]

The control is supposed to go to startup_32 label in boot/compressed/head_64.S, which is the 32-bit entry point.

BUT, startup_32 is in .head.text section and the section starts at address 0x0. (look below)

[image]

**So effectively, startup_32 will be having address 0x0. But how is the control reaching there when we are jumping to 0x100000?**

Comment: Could you copy and paste the source code you're referring to (format it as source code using `\`\`\`asm` before and `\`\`\`` after) and link to the source? I'm having a hard time reading your pictures.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)